# Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80004005 while running a .NET 6 Console App in Windows server

Tags: .net-6.0, coreclr

While I’m deploying .Net 6 console application into the Pseudo Server, I’m getting this error.
The same runtime has been installed in the test server and it works fine.

Enabled trace to see more info about this error.

CoreCLR path = ‘C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.8\coreclr.dll’, CoreCLR dir = ‘C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.8’
Loaded library from C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.8\coreclr.dll
Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80004005

Could use some help to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone having this issue, I have solved this error on my computer by simply:

- Uninstall any Dotnet runtime or DotNet SDK installed on the machine
- goto Program Files and delete the Dotnet folder (yes, all of it.)
- reinstall the Dotnet 6.0 runtime.

Comment: I had the same issue as OP. I was unable to debug my .NET 6 app in VS Professional 2022 17.6 after I switched from the Community edition (probably upgrading .NET 6 Ruuntime). Deleteing 'dotnet' folders in 'Program Files' and 'Program Files (x86)' as well as fresh install of VS Prof helped.

Answer (score -2):

I fixed the problem by change the .NET target runtime.

You can do this like the following:

1. In your Solution Explorer, right-click your project, and select Properties
2. In Properties, go to the Application option on the side menu
3. Locate the Target framework dropdown and select the framework version you need

[image]

Comment: How is this a proper solution? This will just result in downgrading the overall project level with no apparent reason instead of solving the underlining issue.